# Using global variables for Less in Angular

Tags: css, angular, less, angular6

I set up my project as Less in Angular to use the benefits of variables and such in my CSS. But the problem is that I have to define those variables in each component which doesn't make it as efficient. Is there a way to set the variables globaly?

So I want to get rid of this:

In my component less:

```
@pink-color: #FC9DB5; // I want to get this from a single
                      // file which I import on each component
header {
  background-color: @pink-color;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You should `@import` them.

Comment: Ah thanks that actually worked..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what `@import` is for; it lets you import files of variables.